# How to compile imported ES6 node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I have an app written in ES6, and I am using babel to transform all of the files within that app. This app also includes a node_module with React components (that is also written in ES6).

I am importing the components like so:

```
import { Box } from 'components/Box'
```

When I run

```
babel-node --presets es2015,stage-0,react
```

on the file that is importing the Box component, I get an error in the components/Box file on line 1:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, { Component } from 'react'
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I think the reason why this is happening is because babel-node is not transpiling the node_modules. Which, makes sense, since most node modules are written in commonjs format. Is there a way to whitelist this particular node-module so it can be transpiled?

Comment: You cannot disable this on a per-import case. Either module syntax is transpiled or it's not.

Comment: By reading the docs it looks like you can do `--ignore [regex]`. I'd try that.

Comment: I have an example that does exactly this: https://github.com/futurechan/react-flux-relay-express

Comment: @elclanrs pointed out the docs, look at : https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/ there is a specific part about it.

Comment: Links that might help are https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5501, https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/ and https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/. Normally that patterns that specify what babel should transpile exclude node_modules so you'll need to change that or specify packages you want to process.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info? maybe the other files you are referring to? what are you trying to achieve?

I tried running the following `package.json` and it worked just fine.

```
{
  "name": "babel-node-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "something.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^0.14.7"
  }
}
```

with these files as test:

`something.js`

```
import { Box } from './components/Box';
```

and 
`components/box.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Box extends Component{

}

export default Box;
```

Also, on a side note, quoting from the docs:

> Not meant for production use You should not be using babel-node in
>   production. It is unnecessarily heavy, with high memory usage due to
>   the cache being stored in memory. You will also always experience a
>   startup performance penalty as the entire app needs to be compiled on
>   the fly.

why not use any of the build systems mentioned here https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/

Comment: Instead of putting `components/box.js` in the same app. Create a node_module with the same file and then import that file from the main app. Babel won't compile ES6 files in node_modules.